# How I can show textarea content in multiline in the browser by django template?

Tags: css, django

I use Django. My text field was created by RichTextField. In the browser, the text does not break to multiline and exceed from container class like below:

```
References References References References References References References References References References References References References References References References References References References References References References References References References References References
```

I want to show text like this in HTML format:

References References References References References References References References References References References References References References References References References References References References References References References References References References References

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use a safe filter for show HTML format and word-wrap: break-word to show in multiline.

```
<div style="word-wrap: break-word;"> {{ node.references|safe }} </div>
```